# How to automatically move and rotate bones based on proximity to objects

Tags: rigging

So I need this hand model to grab on to things that are close to it, I need the fingers to adapt to the shape of the object it'll grab, but mainly it should be able to grab spheres and cylinders. I'd prefer if I didn't have to select the specific object it grabs, i'd like to it just grab the closest object. Of course, I want all this to happen automatically, without manually moving the bones. What would be the best way of going about this? and some links to the relevant resources for learning how to do it would be helpful. Thanks in advance!! [image]

[image]

Comment: There are things you could potentially do, but the reality is, this just isn't done, because it's complicated and because it gets in the way of animator control. If you want to grab something, you pose the bones appropriately.  That's what they're for.